# First Interview as Junior Java Consultant (Germany) - what to expect?

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I am currently preparing for a job interview as a junior java consultant in Germany.
After sending in my CV and other stuff a small phone interview, which directly started with telling me they are interested in my position and a little small talk about some interesting stuff I do in my free time, I got invited to the interview.

The leading consultant of location and a project manager will be joining the interview and I was told to prepare for a 2 hour interview.

As I have no experience yet what will happen in a interview for a consultant job I would like to have some recommendations for what to prepare.
Is it usual in Germany to solve programming issues in such interviews? I have seen lots of threads regarding this situation in the USA but I am not familiar with the typical German behavior.

To my person:
I have done a job education and worked for 6 months full time as a network engineer before I started to study computer sciences in Germany. I graduated some months ago and am currently working full-time for a local company. The reason to switch is that I want to go into consulting area and also have much more career opportunities than in a small company. I am experienced in developing with JavaSE and have also worked a bit with JavaEE, JSP and Apache Tomcat and also web-technologies like JQuery, html, CSS. As I would not say I am perfectly ready to join an experienced job level as consultant I have directly applied to a junior position to include training. At least I think it's better to be a bit more qualified as junior than try to act like an experienced consultant.

So - do you have any recommendations for what to prepare in terms of such a position? I am quite a good and free speaker so there is no problem presenting my self - but feel free to give advice in any direction :-)

Comment: if any downvotes would give a hint on what you didn't like on my question?

Comment: They will know from your CV, that your previous decades wouldn't be very important. They will likely try to know, how reliable are you and how well went your studies. You have no experience to avoid them to learn the truth, so you don't need to tune too much. Learn the company, learn what sounds the best, if you have some bad spot in your history, have an expalantion. Explain your ideas, what do you want, if they ask (to have a professional career).

Answer (score 2):

Does the job have a job specification? Are they using competency based interviewing? Current  best  practice in interviewing is to have a job description that includes the competencies required  and examples.

Even if they are not using competency based interviewing the job description should give you an idea of what  things they are looking for – go through the job spec and make a list of the key elements and prepare in outline how you meet those requirements –  bullet points  on index cards is a good way to do this.

Comment: yes there is a description and spec which I have already used to mark requirements. I was not told that there is a competency based interviewing, but that does not have to be a reason that there is none. Do you have any other recommondations regarding jobs in the consulting sector?